# Bug in s-expr printing function

Tags: haskell, lisp, scheme, s-expression

To practice my Haskell skills, I'm following the [Write Yourself a Scheme](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/scheme_in_48/tutorial/parser.html) tutorial. I've implemented a parser for s-expressions, but I'm having trouble with the printing function.

When I run the following program

```
main :: IO ()
main  =  do args <- getArgs
            putStrLn $ readExpr (args !! 0)
```

it parses the s-expressions correctly, but when I define my own `shows` instead of `deriving` it, I get erroneous output for nested lists and lists inside vectors:

```
$ ./parser "(1 (2) 3)"
(1 (2 3))
$ ./parser "#(1 (2) 3)"
#(1 (2 3))
$ ./parser "(1 (2 (3)) 4)"
(1 (2 (3 4)))
$ ./parser "(1 (2 (3)) (4))"
(1 (2 (3 (4))))
```

Other cases and nested vectors work fine, though:

```
lars@zygmunt:~/src/scm48$ ./parser "(1 #(2) 3)"
(1 #(2) 3)
lars@zygmunt:~/src/scm48$ ./parser "#(1 #(2) 3)"
#(1 #(2) 3)
lars@zygmunt:~/src/scm48$ ./parser "(1 (2 3))"
(1 (2 3))
```

I've changed the representation of `LispVal` to include `Nil` and `Pair` constructors instead of `List` and `DottedList`, as these match better with the Scheme data model. Printing lists is done by

```
showsVal :: Value -> ShowS
showsVal Nil              =  ("()" ++)
showsVal (Pair x y)       =  ("(" ++) . showsPair x y . (++ ")")
showsVal (String s)       =  shows s
showsVal (Symbol n)       =  (n ++)
showsVal (Number x)       =  shows x
showsVal (Boolean True)   =  ("#t" ++)
showsVal (Boolean False)  =  ("#f" ++)
showsVal (Vector v)       =  ("#(" ++) . showsVec v . (")" ++)

showsPair x Nil         =  showsVal x
showsPair x (Pair y z)  =  (showsVal x) . (" " ++) . showsPair y z
showsPair x y           =  (showsVal x) . (" . " ++) . (showsVal y)

showsVec []      =  id
showsVec [x]     =  shows x
showsVec (x:xs)  =  shows x . (" " ++) . showsVec xs
```

I suspect the error is in `showsPair`, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Hmm.  How do you know the parsing is correct?

Comment: Like the prior comment: you're testing both the parser and the printer at once: why not formulate separate test cases to see which one contains the bug?

Comment: @ephemient: I know the parsing is correct because when I use `deriving Show`, it prints the right structure in Haskell notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out myself:

```
showsVal (Pair x y)  =  ("(" ++) . showsPair x y . (++ ")")
```

should have been

```
showsVal (Pair x y)  =  ("(" ++) . showsPair x y . (")" ++)
                                                --  ^^^^^^
```

Comment: You can avoid this problem if you use `showString` and `showChar`, e.g.: `showsVal (Pair x y)  =  showChar '(' . showsPair x y . showChar ')'` - there's even a showParens function to make it simpler still.